# Very very very simple email option

Tags: email, templates

I am looking for a VERY simple method to allow for computer illiterate people to set up emailers and be able to send them on to others.

Basically, our client is a franchise chain of about 44 and mostly consisting of stay at home mom's. They would all like to keep in contact with one another via an email campaign of sorts but this needs to be super simple for them.

Here's what we know about them:

1. The would like to add photos but know nothing about image cropping/resizing or manipulation.
2. They would need it in the form of an .oft template so that they can just copy and paste.

These are the biggest hurdles. My suggestion to them would be this:

1. Set up an .oft template which they can open from Outlook and start editing.
2. Find an online tool where they can upload their images and it spits out the correct sizes for them

Does anyone have another idea of something similar please? As far as I am aware, only Outlook 2003 runs .oft templates still?

Many thanks!

Comment: Could you clarify why you think this is a programming question that belongs on Stack Overflow and not a user question that belongs on Super User?

Comment: Didn't know that option was available dmckee :)

Comment: There are lots of sites these days (see the bottom of the page, and don't neglect the beta sites to be found at area51). That means more things are on topic *somewhere*, but also more decisions to make...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you considered MailChimp ?

http://www.mailchimp.com/features